# Why does ~~Infinity return 0?

Tags: javascript, bitwise-operators, bitwise-not

Recently I have been playing around with the double [bitwise not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#(Bitwise_NOT)) (`~~`) operator in JavaScript.

I noticed that `~~Infinity` returns `0`. *Why* is this?

I would *expect* it to return `Infinity`, similarly to how `Math.trunc(Infinity)` returns `Infinity` and not `0`.

```js
console.log(~~Infinity) // 0? Expected Infinity
console.log(Math.trunc(Infinity)); // Infinity (as expected)
```